# Should I update Laravel version?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5

I just got assigned a programming job. The code that I was given uses Laravel 4.1.31 but the documentation on the Laravel website supports everything above 4.2. 
I think I should change my Laravel version to 5.0. What version of Laravel should I download? Will I be able to run the program if I install Laravel 5? I haven't downloaded Laravel yet. I just started working with Laravel by watching a couple tutorials so I am still quite confused.

Comment: Laravel changed significantly from v4 to v5. So you'll probably have a lot of work to do upgrading your code to work with v5. Definitely something I'd recommend in general, just don't expect it to be a quick upgrade if you have a lot of v4 code.

Comment: Documentation for 4.1 is still available on github https://github.com/laravel/docs/tree/4.1

Comment: My main question is what version of Laravel should I install on my machine? Will I be able to run the program if I install Laravel 5 on my machine? If I install Laravel 4 on my computer, will I be able to update the program's Laravel to 5.0?

Comment: I'd suggest you first start working with the code you currently have and understand the general philosophy behind Laravel, and then upgrade to 5.x. After you've been acquainted to Laravel 4.1 you can check migration guides to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

When you're starting a new app from scratch, latest version is always the way to go.. but if you already have an application written in an older version, things change..

there are a few points to be considered before making the upgrade..
Why you would want to upgrade.. like you should consider upgrading if:
1. You're having issues with the existing codebase?
2. You need some library in your project that only support the newer version?

There may be any number of other reasons as well.. And being specific to L4 to L5 upgrade, there are significant number of changes in L5 from L4.. The directory structure is completely different. Heavy use of namespaces.. HTML/Form package not available by default, you'll need to fetch & register service provider/facade for them.. if you're using them in your views..

Answer (score 1):

This question is too broad and opinion based .

anyway there is no doubt that laravel 5.2 is a good choice , yet anything above Version 5 is fine. because a newer version of the framework means more stuff to make things smoother and easier.

**EDIT**

check the laravel upgrade documentation

[DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade)

Comment: Will I be able to run the program if I install Laravel 5?

Comment: ofc you have to make a lot of changes. and check this it might help https://laravelshift.com/